# Place table at the top of page

Tags: tables, floats

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % showframe
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Fancy Header}}
\label{table:fundsummary}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small{This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes.}\vspace{2ex}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Averages}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Factor 1}&{Factor 2}&{Factor 3}&{Factor 4}&{Factor 5}\\\midrule
Section 1       &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 2\\
Section 2.2     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 2.3     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 2.4     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 3\\
Section 3.1     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 3.2     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 3.3     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 4\\
Section 4.1     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 4.2     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 4.3     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 5\\
Section 5.1     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 5.2     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 5.3     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

which produces this output:

[image: Table]

For all the tables in my report that does not fill an entire page, I have that they appear at the top of a new page. I switch between `tp` and `ht`, at `\begin{table}[]`, which works for all my other tables. But for some reason, it does not work here. When I use `ht`, as in the this example, it places the table at the bottom of the page. If I use `tp`, it places the table all by itself on a new page.

I apologize if this question is way too simple, but I have yet to figure out how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just change `\begin{table}[ht]` to `\begin{table}[t]`. `ht` means "here if possible, otherwise at the top". In this case, it is possible to put "here", so it does. `t` means "at the top" only. Furthermore, it would be better if you used `p` to insert in a "float page" too: `\begin{table}[tp]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is solved by [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) comment, this answer is focused on off topic issues:

- however since you load the  package `tabularx` it can be exploited in table design (which gives according to my taste nicer result).
- you define eight columns in table but use only seven:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % showframe
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[tp]                       % <--- considered Phelype Oleinik's comments
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\centering
%\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2,
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
         }
\caption{\large{Fancy Header}}
\label{table:fundsummary}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small
This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes. This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes.}

\medskip
%\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{5}{S}                  % <--- changed
                }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{Description}
    & {\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{Variable}}
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Averages}\\
    \cmidrule{3-7}
    &               & \mcx{Factor 1} & \mcx{Factor 2} & \mcx{Factor 3} & \mcx{Factor 4} & \mcx{Factor 5}    \\
    \midrule
Section 1   & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
    \midrule
Section 2   &       &                &                &                &                &                   \\
Section 2.2 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 2.3 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 2.4 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
    \midrule
Section 3   &       &                &                &                &                &                   \\
Section 3.2 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 3.3 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 3.4 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
    \midrule
Section 4   &       &                &                &                &                &                   \\
Section 4.2 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 4.3 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 4.4 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
    \midrule
Section 5   &       &                &                &                &                &                   \\
Section 5.2 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 5.3 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
Section 5.4 & 11.11 & 22.22          & 33.33          & 44.44          & 55.55          & 66.66             \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]