# Add stars to number in parentheses

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

I have this code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % showframe
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Header}}
\label{table:fundsummary}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small{This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes.}\vspace{2ex}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{7}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Averages}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{p-value}&{Factor 1}&{Factor 2}&{Factor 3}&{Factor 4}\\\midrule
Section 1.1     &11.11 &22.22{***} &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 1.2     &11.11 &(22.22){***} &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 1.3     &11.11 &22.22{***} &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 1.4     &11.11 &(22.22){***} &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output

[image: Table]

I have a table, where I have placed t-statistics in parentheses along with a set of stars to denote significance levels. It works perfectly fine when the t-statistic is not in parentheses, but it returns an error otherwise. Is it possible to have both the parentheses and the stars for the same value with the siunitx package? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, it is possible: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430283/table-with-numbers-in-parentheses-in-siunitx?rq=1 (actually, your question is duplicate to this). for your tablew please see answer on your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433248/place-table-at-the-top-of-page).

Comment: @Zarko: Thank you for your comment. Maybe I am missing something, but I am not really sure how my question is an exact duplicate of the one you have linked to. In that question, it seems that the person wants to be able to write: _numeric(numeric)_, while I am trying to write: _(numeric){non-numeric}_, if that makes sense. And thank you for your answer to my other question. I'll take a look at it in a minute.

Comment: answers in given link solve your problem. however all words in question aren't the same as in your question. not numeric cells content simply write as `{what ewer}`, as you already do in columns' headers of your question. to clarify your question (to see in what it is different), please edit your mwe that it will show your problem.

Answer (score 1):

While you could take the approach outlined within the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430290/134641) linked in [Zarko's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433263/add-stars-to-number-in-parentheses/433264#comment1085889_433263), you could alternatively simply place all non-numerical input within braces, as you did with `***`: `{(}22.22{)}{***}`.

You will, however, also need to adjust your column format, as `2.2` no longer provides for sufficient space, including the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some of the t-statistics, which needs to be in parentheses can also take a minus sign. This means that when I adjust the column format to a number larger than 2.2 it can make it fit just fine for the negative numbers, but for the positive numbers, there will be a gap between the left parentheses and the number. Maybe I am just not changing the right number(s) in the set-up?